# When Liskov Substitution refers to subtypes, is it talking about derived classes in the context of C#?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

I'm unfamiliar with the word 'subtype' after looking at [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

I took Liskov substitution to mean if you have a method that takes an `Animal`, you should be able to pass in a `Cat` or an `Animal` where `Cat : Animal` without any unintended side effects.

Is this what Liskov substitution refers to?

Comment: Yes, basically. Of course there usually *will* be distinguishable differences, otherwise we wouldn't bother with different subclasses - but so long as they all obey the contract of the interface/base class, and that's all the client depends on, it should all work. (I felt this was too basic to add as an answer though.)

Comment: Why voting to close this question as "not constructive"?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it maybe referred to the way you can use types like int/double in place of each other. If you put it in the answer box, I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Seems a very reasonable question to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. Anything that takes an Animal should be able to take a Dog, a Cat, and subclasses (breeds, if you like). The methods will be compatible.

Note also that preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype, nor can postconditions be weakened. Otherwise you could slot in a particular subtype and that would break because the surrounding code had imposed certain preconditions that the subclass couldn't tolerate. This can be difficult to implement in practise - see [the circle/ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) for more info.

Comment: +1 for pre- and post-conditions. Because that's what it's all about when talking about Liskov in the context of a strongly typed language.

Comment: That looks interesting, reading it now. I was wondering how exactly you violate the principle, since due to c# being strongly typed you can't access any properties that don't exist by mistake.

Comment: So would you say the Liskov Principle is being broken in that situation because a `Circle` is not a type of `Ellipse`? And this is proven by `stretchX` not being a valid operation on a `Circle`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Likov's Substitution Principle states that if a program module is using a Base class, then the reference to the Base class can be replaced with a Derived class without affecting the functionality of the program module.